# Error in the truffle init command, quorum

Tags: truffle, quorum, ubuntu

i'm trying to truffle a project but each time it shows me this message,
whereas, i'm sure i installed the truffle successfully.

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~/quorum-examples$ cd project
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~/quorum-examples/project$ truffle init
truffle: command not found
```

my ubuntu machine version is 16.04

Answer (score 1):

you should install truffle globally to avoid problems with: npm install -g truffle. 
If you want to install it locally you should specify the truffle root using: ./node_modules/.bin/truffle init
or add the path to ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

qourum-examples is a plain vanilla ubuntu vm. Anything thats missing, including node, npm, truffle and co should be installed first.

Answer (score -1):

Truffle should be installed locally and not in the virtual machine.

Following the [tutorial](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains) on truffle's site will explain you a lot of things and get you going.